# Data Loops Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, data-structures

I have two dataframes:

df_id:

```
name         id
region 01    850
region 01    15062
region 02    851
```

df_combination:

```
Origin      destination    total
region 01   region 01      1954
region 01   region 02      39
```

I have to perform all the possible combinations between region 01 and region 02 and divide the total between the total number of combinations.

Something like this output:

```
Origin_id       Destination_id       Total_division
850             850                  488.5
850             15062                488.5
15062           850                  488.5
15062           15062                488.5
850             851                  19.5
15062           851                  19.5
```

I have more than 300 regions, so I wonder if do it by python code (maybe loop) would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you exactly what you want and efficiently ;-)
It builds a dataframe for each row in df_combination and concatenate them all at the end.

```py
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

dict_region_to_ids = {reg: list(ids) for reg, ids in df_id.groupby("name")["id"]}
dfs = []
for r1, r2, total in df_combination.itertuples(index=False):
    df = pd.DataFrame(product(dict_region_to_ids[r1], dict_region_to_ids[r2]), 
                      columns=["Origin_id", "Destination_id"])
    df["Total_division"] = total / len(df)
    dfs.append(df)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df
```

[image]

Comment: OMG!! You saved my life!!! Thank yoou SOOOOOOO MUCH!!!!!!!!! <3

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion:

```
df = df_combination.merge(df_id, left_on='Origin', right_on='name')
df = df.merge(df_id, left_on='destination', right_on='name')
for _, group in df.groupby(['Origin', 'destination']):
    df.loc[group.index, 'total'] /= group.shape[0]
df = df[['id_x', 'id_y', 'total']].rename(
            columns={'id_x': 'Origin_id', 'id_y': 'Destination_id',
                     'total': 'Total_division'}
        )
```

Result (`print(df)`):

```
   Origin_id  Destination_id  Total_division
0        850             850           488.5
1        850           15062           488.5
2      15062             850           488.5
3      15062           15062           488.5
4        850             851            19.5
5      15062             851            19.5
```